# "Disbalanced" vs. "unbalanced"

Tags: differences, adjectives, past-participles, negative-prefixes

What are the differences in usage between *disbalanced* and *unbalanced*?

Comment: While we're at it, how does 'imbalanced' fit into the picture?

Answer (score 12):

Well, "disbalanced" apparently is not a currently used English word. It existed but it's not used anymore, since it doesn't appear in the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/spellcheck/?q=disbalanced), nor in the NOAD. And when I was editing your question my browser signalled it as "wrong".

*[Unbalanced](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/unbalanced)* is used when you want to define something as not equally distributed, to define a person as mentally ill or disturbed or when someone is "*giving too much or too little importance to one part or aspect of something*". [OALD]

Comment: Oh why the -1? If someone thinks this answer is wrong or not useful, you can directly post a comment about it.

Comment: It is an English word. See below.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Corrected.

Comment: Voted up again :)

Answer (score 6):

The Oxford English Dictionary (OED) has an entry for *disbalance*, meaning *to disturb the balance or equilibrium of, to put out of balance*.  Its derived adjective *disbalanced* is also included, with a citation from 1885. I'm not surprised that it's not to be found in Alenanno's sources, as it must be rare now, if not exactly obsolete.

*Unbalanced* is defined in the OED as *not balanced or equably poised*.

Answer (score 1):

*unbalanced* means something is not currently balanced and has never been **IN** balance;

*disbalanced* indicates something which is not currently balanced but **WAS** in balance at some point.

Comment: You should include the relative non-use of *disbalance* in any definition. As you portray it, it sounds like a word in use.

Comment: @virmaior: try [Google books for recent examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22disbalanced%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2014&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl) though the names of many of the authors suggest English might not be their first language

Comment: @Henry - made my comment **after** looking at the ngram.

Comment: The [ngram is very strange](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unbalanced%2Cimbalanced%2Cdisbalanced&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cunbalanced%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunbalanced%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnbalanced%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cimbalanced%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bimbalanced%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BImbalanced%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisbalanced%3B%2Cc0) as it tells me *'Search for "disbalanced" yielded only one result'* even though it then gives me over 200 examples